# macOS - updating scripts - moving from rsync 2.6.9 to 3.0.6

Tags: macos, metadata, acl, rsync

We are using `rsync` on macOS to migrate a specific user's home directory from **OLD** (current) to **NEW** computer.

User is in possession of **OLD** computer...we are in possession of **NEW** computer.

Both computers are bound to Active Directory, and our script preserves UID/GID, resource forks, etc.

Apple bundles `rsync` 2.6.9 we need to use `-E` to "copy extended attributes", however an unfortunate draw back is full vs delta is broken...every run of `rsync` is treated as a full run.

`rsync` 3 fixes this, able to "copy extended attributes" without breaking follow up runs...however due to changes from **GNU v2** to **GNU v3**, [Apple and LinusT have flipped **GNU v3** the bird (deservingly so)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaKIZ7gJlRU).

We engaged Apple on how to update `rsync` to 3.0.6 without breaking any of our Developers' workflows, and they suggested we pick a folder and invoke using a specific path...so we picked `/Library/COMPANY/Applications/rsync` as the install path, where `/Library/COMPANY/Applications/rsync/bin/rsync` becomes the path to the binary.

Technician would ssh to the user's **OLD** computer and run `/Library/COMPANY/Scripts/rsyncStuff.sh` which would prompt for criteria and in short would run a command like this:

```
/usr/bin/rsync --log-file=/Library/Logs/rsyncTransfer_${dateStamp}.log --exclude '<stuff>' --archive --verbose --delete --extended-attributes --progress --recursive --human-readable -e ssh /Users/jdoe adminUser@${NEWcomputerIpAddress}:/Users/Shared/
```

We studied the differences between `rsync` 2.6.9 and 3.0.6 and our best guess would be this command would do essentially the same thing:

```
/Library/COMPANY/Applications/rsync/bin/rsync --log-file=/Library/Logs/rsyncTransfer_${dateStamp}.log --exclude '<stuff>' --archive --verbose --delete --xattrs --acls --progress --recursive --human-readable -e ssh /Users/jdoe adminName@${NEWcomputerIpAddress}:/Users/Shared/
```

Notice `rsync` 2.6.9 used `--extended-attributes`, where `rsync` 3.0.6 uses `--xattrs --acls`. Sanity check, does this seem right?

A colleague asked if we should be using `--rsync-path=PROGRAM`, which existed in 2.6.9, wasn't sure if it is needed, since tech is invoking our script, and we manage the command including the path to `rsync`...sanity check, just in case. :)

[EDIT: Confirmed `--rsync-path=PROGRAM` is not needed.]

TIA,
Don

Comment: Consider Truck.app.  I wrote it exactly for this sort of reason.  It carries the most modern rsync and makes using it as simple as drag-and-drop.  http://bonhardcomputing.com/truck/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon Davisson's responses were extremely helpful.

The "answer" would be, read his responses, and choose which options he mentions are useful, depending on your environment, and how you manage your Macs.

In short, installing rsync 3.0.6 worked like a charm, and happens to be the version Mike Bombich uses for Carbon Copy Cloner. He works for Apple now, so I trust his judgement. :)

In our case, we can't enable root, so once rsync is complete, move the folder from /Users/Shared/jdoe to /Users/jdoe and recursively set owner to jdoe.

George Davisson's advice was a real eye opener, specifically the closing comments regarding why /Users/jdoe (on old computer) rsync'd to /Users/shared/jdoe (on new computer) has to be recursively set to jdoe as owner. The reason we have to do this is we can't enable root, but some folks might be able to enable root and that'll make the rsync process fewer steps.

Here is our final tested command...as always, we're always looking to improve our processes, so we are open to any future suggestions/changes:

```
/Library/COMPANY/Applications/rsync/bin/rsync --rsync-path=/Library/ATOS/Applications/rsync/bin/rsync --log-file=${logFolder}/rsyncTransfer_${dateStamp}.log --exclude '.Trash' --exclude '.DS_Store' --exclude 'Library/Caches' --exclude 'Library/Keychains' --exclude 'Library/Saved Application State' --exclude 'Box Documents' --exclude 'Box Sync' --archive --verbose --acls --xattrs  --delete --progress --recursive --human-readable -e ssh /Users/${userName} ${adminName}@${ipAddress}:/Users/Shared/
```

Once rsync is done, run `sudo mv /Users/Shared/${username} /Users/${username}` and `sudo chown -R ${username} /Users/${username}` and have user log in.

Thanks again to Gordon Davisson for all the awesome input!

Answer (score 1):

Short summary: if you want extended attributes, don't transfer between rsync v2 and v3; pick one, and use it on both ends.

Longer explanation: in order to support extended attributes (and Finder flags, and all the other nonstandard metadata HFS+ supports), Apple modified the rsync v2.x that comes with macOS to use the [AppleDouble format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleSingle_and_AppleDouble_formats). In addition to all of the real files, it syncs fake metadata "files" with a "._" prefix -- that is, if you had a file named "notes.txt", it'd sync both "notes.txt" and "._notes.txt" with the latter containing the file's metadata. Delta transfers should work fine for the main file, but aren't supported for the metadata file; this shouldn't matter too much, since the metadata files are generally pretty small.

rsync v3, on the other hand, added extensible metadata to the standard... in a completely different and incompatible way. I don't remember how thoroughly I've tested this, but IIRC if you try to transfer extended metadata from v3 to v2, it'll reject it because the remote (v2) doesn't support that feature. If you try it from Apple's v2 to v3, you'll get a bunch of actual "._" files, 'cause the receiver doesn't recognize them as metadata.

Also, you're correct about the different command-line options, but on v3 you may also want `--ctimes` (preserve creation times) and `--fileflags` (preserves flags). Although that last one comes with a warning: I've run into trouble with v3 locking files (due to transferring the `uchg` file flag) and then failing to set their other attributes.

Personally, I prefer to use v3, so I just copy it onto the computers I'm going to be transferring between. I generally install it as /usr/local/bin/rsync3, so there's no ambiguity about which version is being used.

Comment: Hi Gordon, yes we are using rsync 3.0.6 on both ends, I guess the `--rsync-path=PROGRAM` option was confusing. First sync worked fine without it. Second sync didn't work without it:

`--rsync-path=/Library/COMPANY/Applications/rsync/bin/rsync`

FWIW, using `-E` works in version 2.6.9, but breaks delta sync...so every run is full run.

I'll have another go tomorrow to see if full, followed by delta, both work as needed, and will post back here.

Comment: Ok, the delta finished faster than I thought. So the `--rsync-path=PROGRAM` wasn't needed for the full, but it was needed for the delta. Now I need to figure out why the home directory is owned by the account that did the `ssh`. When we set this up with 2.6.9, the UID/GID of the folder was preserved. 3.0.6 seems to change that to the `ssh` account. I wonder if `--acls` is not working. Will test tomorrow (for real this time).

Comment: v2 with `-E` shouldn't completely break delta sync -- it wont't do delta for the metadata files, so you'll wind up with a huge list of files being transferred, but since it's just the metadata it shouldn't matter. As for v3 and `--acls`, my understanding is that it implies `-p` (permissions aka mode bits), but not `-og` (owner and group assignment).

Comment: Checked and looks like `--ctimes` isn't needed, which is fine since after reading your response I verified that files come over without that changing. #wipesBrow :) Agreed regarding `--fileflags`, weighing the pluses and minuses, will avoid that one. :) Soooooo...the remaining problem is the user's home directory UID/GID is not being preserved...seems to end with the folder being owned by the account used to perform the transfer...strange as I've got `--owner`, `--group`, and `--acls` in the command. I'll post "[EDIT 20180626]" to add the current iteration of the command.

Comment: @donmontalvo Is the receiving instance of `rsync` running as root? If not, it cannot set file ownership (and is limited on group assignment as well).

Comment: Yes, script is invoked using sudo. Did more testing on 3.0.6 (both computers). `--ctimes` isn't an option, and I'll avoid `--fileflags` to avoid locked file headaches. Full/delta syncs are working fine. I can't seem to get the GID/UID of the user's home directory to stick. I added `--owner`, `--group`, and `--acls`, but no luck.

Comment: @donmontalvo Using `sudo` gets it root access on the local computer, but not the remote; the command you give connects to the remote as adminUser rather than root, and admin users aren't (directly) allowed to change file ownership. You'll either need to ssh in as root, or run `sudo rsync` on the *destination* computer, and ssh into the source computer as a user that has read access to everything that needs to be synced.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the explanation. We don't enable root (CIS compliance). This morning I tested rsync OLD>NEW, then I recursively setting owner to user's LDAP name (for example "jdoe001"), and the user was able to log in to the new computer, the home directly linked up. I think we're good...thanks a LOT for all the selfless assistance, love this forum!